Alternate idiomatic phrase to say "Strike while the iron is hot"?
There is a famous metaphor (translated) in Hindi,

The iron is hot, strike with the hammer.

Google Search/ChatGPT returned the English equivalent ‘Strike while the iron is hot’.
Are there other equivalent phrases conveying the same meaning.
I used the phrase recently, ‘My stocks are high right now, I should cash-out’. Does it convey the same meaning?

I'm unclear.  "Strike while the iron is hot" is  proverb, and used figuratively (you aren't talking about real "iron")  but  "My stocks are high right now, I should cash-out" is not a proverb, its just a literal piece of English

@JamesK Yes, it (stocks...) is not a proverb; I used it in a sentence, and wondered if it is a correct expression. My research --from hindi proverb--  took me to iron.... proverb. I am wondering if there are other expressions coveying the same meaning?

What's your concern with "My stocks are high right now, I should cash-out"? It's not a proverb, so, unlike "strike while the iron is hot" you can't use  My stocks are high right now, I should cash-out" to talk about anything except stocks.  You can use "strike while the iron is hot" to talk about anything.

It just happens there is another proverb with a similar meaning "make hay while the sun shines"

@James I was going to mention that one too, but to me it isn't quite the same as "strike while the iron is hot." Logically, as a metaphor "make hay while the sun shines" has the exact same meaning... but they just feel different to me. Matter of opinion perhaps.

Do you mean that, when your stocks are high, that might be a good time to use either “Strike while the iron is hot” or the Hindi proverb? If so, yes, they appear to be equivalent. But please edit because right now your question seems to be different.

@Eric "Strike while the iron is hot" is a saying in English too. You can find it in the poem 'The way to succeed' written by Rev. Norman Macleod in the nineteenth century.

There is another saying with similar meaning "Make hay while the sun shines".  both have the proverbial meaning "act now (because if you wait things won't get any better)"
There's no grammar errors in your sentence about stocks, but it isn't a proverb.
The point of proverbs is that you can use them to give general advice.  I might say "strike while the iron is hot" to mean "You should ask your boss for a raise now, right after your project has been a success"  But I can't say "cash out your stocks while the price is high" to mean "ask your boss for a raise", because that isn't a proverb.

A very informal equivalent would be:

Get it while the getting is good.


—Which doesn't so much mean you won't get "it" if you wait (the way "strike while the iron is hot" does), but that "it" might decline in quality or abundance.

I disagree with that. I think they are exactly equivalent. But I suppose anything like this is open to interpretation.

Not a perfect equivalent, but "quit while you're ahead" (stop taking risks before your luck runs out) has some overlap, especially with the stock analogy.

Yes. Thanks for your answer. I am not exactly quitting, though?

@Eric Hence the caveats.

I heard that Lyndon Johnson would say, “The time to kill a snake is when the hoe is in your hand” but I cannot find him quoted online.

Your situation involving the decision whether to sell stocks is one to which either expression—“Strike while the iron is hit” or (the one that @James K points out) “Make hay while the sun shines”—could be applied.
And there’s a third expression that is not close to the other two, but is exactly applicable to your investing situation: “Buy low, sell high.”
